# iBooks and Notes crashing on startup

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, crash, bug

I installed the iOS 11 Beta, then downgraded back to iOS 10.3.2. I restored to my iCloud backup and everything looked alright. However, I am having issues after the restore, some of which include:

- Backups of Whatsapp conversations will not restore, as it thinks I am not connected to iCloud, despite being listed in iOS Settings.
- iBooks and Notes crash on startup.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

**Update**
After updating to iOS 11, all the probleme were solved and the all the data was restored.

Comment: same here . . .  i guess it's about document scans. Do you have some on your notes ?

Comment: @ArsenSench  nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update to iOS 11, everything will return to normal, with all the data restored.

Answer (score 0):

Same here on an iPad, plus iCloud Drive app was saying I need to enable iCloud Drive, but it's already enabled.

I managed to fix the iCloud Drive app problem.

- Switch off Settings->AppleId Account->iCloud->iCloud Drive
- Reboot
- Switch on Settings->AppleId Account->iCloud->iCloud Drive

Nor ibooks nor notes got fixed.

Any hints with ibooks and notes crashes are welcome.

Comment: After restoring iPad and restoring Backup, notes and iBooks seem to be working again.